# Xpath is Unable to Locate Element.

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

Can anyone help me in writing xPath for below image, I wrote one but it's not working.

[image]

My xPath is `//li[@class='active']//a[@class='dropdown-button btn']`

Comment: Add some more HTML code, starting from descent node (div)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind switching to CSS selectors, use the following:

CSS selector: `#nav-mobile .active a.dropdown-button.btn`

Answer (score 0):

Try using below XPath:

```
//a[@class='dropdown-button btn'];
```

Comment: Thanks For Comment Prasanna, i Tried That To Now its Not Working.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@class='dropdown-button btn']"}

Comment: Are you sure you're within the right context? Is the element maybe part of an iframe? Because the xpath is valid and should match, given that the element exists in your current context and at the time you call it.

Comment: i Used This Code Only

Comment: WebElement e4=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='dropdown-button btn']"));
 Actions a1=new Actions(driver);
 a1.moveToElement(e4).click().build().perform();

Comment: Is Their Any Wrong in Calling The Xpath?

Answer (score 0):

```
//ul[@id="dropdown1"]/preceding-sibling::a
```

Try with the above XPath.

Answer (score 0):

Try below Xpath and share your feedback

```
//*[contains(@class,'active')]/descendant::a[@class='dropdown-button btn']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the xpath from the Chrome/Firefox inspect elements:

```
1- Put the mouse on the element you want to inspect
2- Right click, Inspect element
3- Down bar shows, Right clikc, copy, copy xpath
```

Done!

Answer (score 0):

I think the **li** element gets active only when you hover or click it.
Please try to hover/click on the parent element and then try searching for your XPath.